# How to explain the momentum exchange of two solid particles collision at molecular scale?

Tags: momentum, collision, molecular-dynamics

Here is my question: assume two solid sphere collided to each other in vacuum, at macroscopic, it can be explain by Newton's law. But at molecular scale, does the surface atoms touch to each other or just very close? how the momentum exchange between the atoms?

Cheers.

Comment: Related wiki about "contact forces" : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_degeneracy_pressure

Answer (score -1):

They will not touch. This prevented due to the [Pauli exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle). Also, the electrical repulsion of the electron prevents this. Momentum is conserved, however.

Comment: How the momentum is conserved, if the collision is plastic?

Comment: @Abhijeet Momentum is conserved in *all* collisions without respect to elasticity.

Comment: @jimmy360 i have assumed the frictional heat that will release when these spheres will stick.

Comment: @Abhijeet The spheres generate heat when they hit, but the atoms will not lose momentum to friction and heat.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy, if we assume the particle is formed by a lot of molecular and the particle is electrically neutral, then the particles will not touch because the electrical repulsion between the surface molecular?

Comment: Momentum will be conserved even after friction? It would be great help if you could just elaborate

Answer (score -1):

The cases, assuming the spheres are not rigid:

Collision is perfectly elastic=they will only touch
Inelastic collision=particles can get displaced because of the compression caused
Plastic collision= spheres would stick to each other, the particles will be displaced. 
Thanks